# Android Custom datetime picker disable dates before today's date

Tags: android, android-fragments, calendar, datetimepicker, android-dialogfragment

I have created this Custom DialogFragment to picker Date and time but i dont know how to disable dates before today's date as well as show only 7 days Ex. if todays 10 feb then disable all date before 10 feb and only show dates 10,11,12,14,15,16,17 feb this same goes for thr time disable time before current time.

I know that i have to make some changes in getDatesFromCalendar() method or is there a way to validate the dates and time according to the current date and time.

```
 public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements View.OnClickListener {

 String dates[];
 NumberPicker datePicker, hourPicker, minutePicker;
 Button doneButton, currentTimeButton;
 Calendar rightNow = Calendar.getInstance();


 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     dates = getDatesFromCalender();

 }

 @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     Dialog getDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
     View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, container);
     datePicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
     hourPicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.hourPicker);
     minutePicker = (NumberPicker) view.findViewById(R.id.minutePicker);
     doneButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.doneButton);
     currentTimeButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.currentTimeButton);
     datePicker.setMinValue(0);
     datePicker.setMaxValue(dates.length - 1);
     datePicker.setFormatter(new NumberPicker.Formatter() {

         @Override
         public String format(int value) {
             return dates[value];
         }
     });

     datePicker.setDisplayedValues(dates);
     hourPicker.setMinValue(0);
     hourPicker.setMaxValue(23);
     hourPicker.setValue(rightNow.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
     minutePicker.setMinValue(0);
     minutePicker.setMaxValue(59);
     minutePicker.setValue(rightNow.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
     doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     currentTimeButton.setOnClickListener(this);
     getDialog.setTitle("choose_time");
     return view;
 }

 private String[] getDatesFromCalender() {
     Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
     Calendar c2 = Calendar.getInstance();

     List<String> dates = new ArrayList<String>();
     DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM");
     dates.add(dateFormat.format(c1.getTime()));

     for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
         c1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
         dates.add(dateFormat.format(c1.getTime()));
     }
     c2.add(Calendar.DATE, -60);

     for (int i = 0; i < 60; i++) {
         c2.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
         dates.add(dateFormat.format(c2.getTime()));
     }
     return dates.toArray(new String[dates.size() - 1]);
 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     Bundle args = new Bundle();
     if (v.getId() == R.id.doneButton) {
         //Handle selected time and date
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     } else if (v.getId() == R.id.currentTimeButton) {

     }

 }
```

This is what my requirement is [Click here to see the screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sP6Sx.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure those dates in the screen are "disabled"?  Maybe they are just options you can scroll to by dragging?

Comment: same with my problem. before date not showing.

Comment: @Doug Stevenson I think you didn't get my question, the dates are not disabled and all dates are selectable. My requirement is to disable all the dates before today's date

Comment: @Rashid Cordero In my code before dates are visible but I want to disable them

Comment: Aw. So you need my implementation? But my implementation was the date is totally remove(they cant see the previous date in the datepicker).I will post it tomorrow. Im on mobile right now

Comment: @FaizSk we have different implementation sir, my implementation only applies to dates only which opens a DatePickerDialog

Comment: @RashidCordero I got it to working thanks for the help :)